# htaccess in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel

I've setup a laravel application on a shared server, the direct url works fine but when I access the other pages I receive the error message: The requested URL /contact was not found on this server.

but if I then type "http://unit13productions.co.uk/index.php/contact" this shows the correct page.

I'm not sure if this is the htaccess file or the index.php file?

My file directories on the server are as follow:

unit13 folder:

[image]

public_html folder:

[image]

my file directories inside my index.php is:

autoloader:

```
require __DIR__.'/../unit13/vendor/autoload.php';
```

turn the lights on:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../unit13/bootstrap/app.php';
```

contents of my htaccess file:

```
AddType x-httpd-php71 .php
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be an issue with your .htaccess file more than anything else. Try renaming your .htaccess file to .htaccess1 just so it isn't used and then create a new one and add the following to it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The details on how to configure your application for either Apache or Nginx is listed on the laravel documentation which I've listed below.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#pretty-urls

Hope this helps!